# Design a table with two main columns but diving the first column again for another two columns in a new row.

Tags: html

[image]

Hi I need to create my table using like shown in the above image. Here I have given the code I tried. Could some1 please explain me the mistake I have made.

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td colspan="2" >Address
<tr><td>Address1</td><td>Address1</td></tr>
</td>
<td rowspan="2">Name</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You scan cells row by row, and you mention a cell in your code as soon as you first hit it. Then you remember any cells that have `colspan` or `rowspan`, and when you reach their other parts in other rows, you don't put anything at all.

```
<table border="1">
  <tr><td colspan="2">Address</td><td rowspan="2">Name</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Address1</td><td>Address2</td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. But isn't there any way to design a table by divide the first column into two cells inside it. As I have done in my code? Sorry if I'm asking a stupid question.